# Draw train and test set once or draw new sets for each fold in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have two scikit-learn models with two different procedures of generating the train and test sets. From my perspective, they should result in the same scores.

**Method 1:**

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
       model = create_model(X[train], Y[train], X[test], Y[test])
       score.append(model.score())
score_mean = mean(score)
```

**Method 2:**

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1, stratify=Y)    
    model = create_model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
    score.append(model.score())
score_mean = mean(score)
```

My score function is the [MCC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html). The first method does a cross-validation with a function, the second one does it explicitly. In Method 2, I get an MCC about 10 times larger than in Method 1.

Is there something fundamentally different in these two methods that explain the different results or are they formally equivalent and there has to be something else responsible in the rest of the code?

Idea: If I use the StratifiedKFold method, it draws samples like this: Given I have 5 samples of class 1 and 5 samples in class 2, the method prepares the folds in such a way that no sample was taken twice (e.g. [0, 4],[3,9],[8,2],[1,6],[5,7], all numbers are chosen once). I think in the second method with train_test_split() the same sample can occur several times. Not sure whether that can skew the MCC so much.

Comment: Are you sure you about method 1? It does not do any cross validation as the resulting model is the one constructed with the 5th fold of your dataset (as you do not reuse the info from the previous models). So to me, method 1 and 2 are doing the same, only selecting different train/test.

Comment: Oh, you're right about the cross-validation. I store the score of each fold in a list and average over it afterwards. I added it to the main-post, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the variance of your score? Does the prerformance changes when you change the random state in method 2?

Comment: For method 1 I get an MCC of about 0.05, sd = 0.001 and for method 2 an MCC of about 0.6, sd = 0.05. It's stable over different random seeds.

Comment: What I don't get is that you should get a std of 0 in **Method 2**. If you set random_state in `train_test_split`, your training and test set will always be the same. The `create_model` method does not always give the same result if you use the same train/test? Can you remove the `random_state` parameter front `train_test_split` to make sure the problem is not that you have an extremly bad split? (I know it is unlikely but still..) If you want to keep this parameter, you should use `train_test_split` only once, outside the loop to avoid misinterpretation (as you always use the same split).

Answer (score -1):

Method 1 is better as it is cross-validating using a different set of test data in each fold. Method 2 is taking random samples but with replacement.

However you also have a bug. Method 2 is using the same random seed on each loop. So you are running the same model 5 times.

Comment: But even if I just look at one fold in Method 1 and leave out the for-loop in Method 2, the scoring is still vastly different. I think the error is connected to the sampling. The mean and variance over the CV is stable, I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Try not setting the seed in method 2 or setting different seeeds and running the 5 loops. One train test split is often poor. What is the mean for each run?